# Change of limits in this Fourier series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series

I found the Fourier series
$$
f(x)=\frac{4k}{\pi}\sum_{n \text{ odd}}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sin(n x) \tag 1
$$
for the square wave function 
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
-k, \quad -\pi <x<0\\
k, \quad 0<x<\pi 
\end{align}
\end{cases}
$$
But the answer is written as
$$
f(x)=\frac{4k}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2n-1}\sin(2n-1)x \tag 2
$$

How can I find $(2)$ from $(1)$?

Comment: Odd numbers can be written as $2n  - 1$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your sum:$\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{4k}{\pi}\sum_{n \text{ odd}}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sin(n x) \tag 1 $
As it clearly states, for odd $n$ this summation have to be calculated.

So we say for odd $n$ we have: $n=2i-1$ where $i=1,2,...$

By substituting this into our summation we have:
$$\begin{align}
 \displaystyle f(x)=\frac{4k}{\pi}\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2i-1}\sin((2i-1) x) 
\end{align}$$
Or in another notation:

$\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{4k}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2n-1}\sin((2n-1) x) \tag 2 $

Comment: You are welcome @JDoeDoe. If you use $n=2i+1$ then $i$ should start from $0$ and not $1$ to have $n=1$. Saying $n=2i+1$ is also correct but since the final notation in the summation used $n=1$ for start of summation, I wrote with $n=2i-1$ to simply say $\sum_{n=1}$ and not  $\sum_{n=0}$

Comment: Hi! I just edited my question so I deleted the comment. :)

Comment: I think I got it. My only problem was if $n=2i-1$, how did you know $i=1,2, \dots$ and not $i=0,1,\dots$ instead? If $i=0$, we have $n=-1$, I guess $n$ has to be positive and therefore $i$ must start at $1$?

Comment: I guess my comment was more in general and not just because equation $(2)$ start with $1$.

Comment: @JDoeDoe $i=1,2,...$ because in the last summation we have $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}$ and not $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}$. If equation $(2)$ was: $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}$ then I would choose $n=2i+1$ as well. About the general question: Trigonometric fourier series start from $0$.

Comment: But here as we eluded even numbers, it starts from 1 and not 0. It's like shifting. You can shift again by $n=2i+1$ and then you can say start from $0$.